# how to convert a string boolean into an IF statement in Python

Tags: python, boolean

I am trying to create a more complicated boolean function that I'll use between functions. Here is the simplified problem:

```
a = "1 == 2"

if a:
    print ("it is not working")
else:
    print ("it worked")
```

Out[1]:

it is not working

Basically  I am trying to pass a function as a string and use that in a boolean later on but it turns out as True always.

I also tried:

bool(a)

Out[1]: True

Comment: "1 == 2" is a string... And any string that is not empty is 'truthy' in python... So that's why its always returning true... If you want 1 == 2 to be evaluated as a Boolean, remove the quotation marks around

Comment: a string is always true if its not None. This sounds like an XY problem. Normally its alwyas discouraged an approach like this where you want to eval a string. However if your insistant on it you should look up `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Is the empty string in Python not evaluated to false?

Comment: @JordanSimba yeah sorry thats what i mean, string is always true unless its empty.

Comment: Try eval(a).  For a = "1 == 2", eval(a) = False.  For a = "1 == 1", eval(a) = True.  [More info on eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval)

Comment: @DarrylG Thank you!!!. That's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [eval](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eval-in-python/)

```
a = "1 == 2"
eval(a)
>>>False

a = "1 == 1"
eval(a) 
>>> True
```